# Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '@P3'. con NativeQuery

Tags: java, hibernate

Estoy creando una consulta con HQL pero al momento de ejecutar el programa me lanza este error.

***java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '@P3'.***

Este error solo se produce que cuando quiero mostrar todas las variedades de un producto, si que creo que el error esta en la condición de variedades

(params.getAllVariety() != null && params.getAllVariety())

Lo raro que cuando esta trabajando con HQL hice la misma consulta y no me lanzaba ese error al ejecutar el programa, si que supongo que si o si es error de sintaxis , pero miro y no encuentro donde podría estar el error, estoy trabajando con syBase

```
public ResultWithSqlQuery dailyHistoricalSeriesInformationTitle(ParamsInfoSeriesHistoricas params) throws DataAccessException {

        String sql = "select distinct p.codigo, tp.pro_des "
                + "from odepa..precio_diario_oficial pd "
                + "join odepa..producto p on pd.codigo_producto = p.codigo "
                + "join odepa..T_producto tp on p.pro_ori_cod = tp.pro_ori_cod "
                + "join odepa..T_grupo_producto gp on tp.pro_ori_cod = gp.gru_pro_ori_cod "
                + "join odepa..T_grupo g on g.gru_cod = gp.gru_pro_gru_cod "
                + "where p.pro_eco_cod = tp.pro_eco_cod "
                + "and p.pro_var_cod = tp.pro_var_cod "
                + "and p.pro_tip_cod = tp.pro_tip_cod "
                + "and p.pro_sec_cod = tp.pro_sec_cod "
                + "and p.pro_sse_cod = tp.pro_sse_cod "
                + "and p.pro_cla_cod = tp.pro_cla_cod "
                + "and p.pro_scl_cod = tp.pro_scl_cod "
                + "and tp.pro_eco_cod = gp.gru_pro_eco_cod "
                + "and tp.pro_var_cod = gp.gru_pro_var_cod "
                + "and tp.pro_tip_cod = gp.gru_pro_tip_cod "
                + "and tp.pro_sec_cod = gp.gru_pro_sec_cod "
                + "and tp.pro_sse_cod = gp.gru_pro_sse_cod "
                + "and tp.pro_cla_cod = gp.gru_pro_cla_cod "
                + "and tp.pro_scl_cod = gp.gru_pro_scl_cod "
                + "and pd.fecha >= :fechaInicio "
                + "and pd.fecha <= :fechaTermino "
                + "and pd.monto_moneda_norm != null ";
        if (params.getAllProduct() != null && params.getAllProduct()) {
            sql += "and gp.gru_pro_gru_cod = gp.gru_pro_gru_cod ";
        } else {
            sql += "and gp.gru_pro_gru_cod = :gruProdCod ";
        }
        if (params.getAllVariety() != null && params.getAllVariety()) {
            sql += "and tp.pro_var_cod = tp.pro_var_cod ";
        } else {
            sql += "and tp.pro_var_cod in :proVarCod ";
        }
        sql += "order by g.gru_cod, tp.pro_des ";

        Session s = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        //Query query = s.createQuery(sql);
        NativeQuery query = s.createNativeQuery(sql);
        query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ResultDiarioSerieHistoricaProductosBasicTitle.class));
        query.addScalar("codigo").addScalar("pro_des");

        query.setParameter("fechaInicio", params.getFirstDate());
        query.setParameter("fechaTermino", params.getEndDate());

        if (params.getAllProduct() != null && !params.getAllProduct()) {
            query.setParameter("gruProdCod", params.getProduct());
        }
        if (params.getAllVariety() != null && !params.getAllVariety()) {
            query.setParameter("proVarCod", params.getVariety());
        }

        ResultWithSqlQuery salida = new ResultWithSqlQuery();
        salida.setResult(query.getResultList());
        salida.setSql(sql);
        return salida;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno buscando encontré que el problema era en la linea

```
sql += "and tp.pro_var_cod in :proVarCod ";
```

Habia que agregar un parentesis

```
sql += "and tp.pro_var_cod in (:proVarCod) ";
```